# Clear/reset button and display the first/placeholder in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have both a dropdown list and a "multiple" dropdown list like below

```
@Html.DropDownList("process", Model.Processes, new { placeholder = "-- select --", style = "width: 100%", multiple = "multiple" })
@Html.DropDownList("products", Model.Products, new { placeholder = "-- select --", style = "width: 100%" })
```

And I used the reset code from this link http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/12/how-to-reset-aspnet-dropdownlist-or.html

I got it to work as I intended, where the values are cleared/reset, but what I would like to ask is how to reset the text in the dropdown list back to either the --select-- part or leave it blank for the "multiple" dropdown. I have a button i used to call the javascript function and i used this code to make it work.

```
function clearAll() {
    $('#products').find('option:first').prop('selected', true);
    $('#products').val('0');
}
```

i tried the .val('0') part but the text on the dropdown still stays the same as what was selected but the value was assigned back to the default.

Comment: So i figured out my issue and it was rather simpler than i thought. i was using the select2 library and i did something like this.         $("#Products").select2('val', 0); and the reset button worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the defaultSelected property of an option element:

Contains the initial value of the selected HTML attribute, indicating whether the option is selected by default or not.
So, the DOM interface already keeps track which option was selected initially.

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
$('#my_select option').prop('selected', function() {
    return this.defaultSelected;
});
```

});

This would even work for multi-select elements.

If you don't want to iterate over all options, but "break" after you found the originally selected one, you can use .each instead:

```
$('#my_select option').each(function () {
if (this.defaultSelected) {
    this.selected = true;
    return false;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `button type="reset"`? This would reset all `input`'s of your form. Also the selects. When you want to reset all your fields I would try this solution because it wouldn't need any additional JavaScript code.

```
<form>
  <select name="select1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2" placeholder="placeholder">
      <option></option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How does this reset type button know which dropdown list (including multiple selects) to reset? Or does it reset all instances of all dropdown lists possible? Edit: I'm an idiot. I didn't read your answer carefully. You said it will reset all "input's in the form. I unfortunately do not have "inputs" in the form. They're mainly in a div tag.

Comment: OK, I just played around a bit with your example on JSFiddle. I think when your jQuery Version is 1.9 or higher your proposed solution should work. What jQuery Version do you use? Maybe you can update it...